# upload multiple files from one input in user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a 4.0 WebForms application that allows users to upload files while submitting a ticket. I've created a user control that has the input field:

`<input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="files" runat="server" onchange="changeFunc()" />`

to select files. The input field is inside of an `UpdatePanel` and the `onchange` uses javascript to click an asp button so that I can start the upload process automatically.

In the click event for the button I've tried using the following code to collect all the files from the input field:

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
   HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[i];
   fileNames.Add(file.FileName);
}
```

Unfortunately, `Files.Count` is always zero not matter how many files I have selected. I seem to be missing something basic here and I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 0):

I was being a dummy and had the button under triggers as `asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger` instead of `asp:PostBackTrigger`